# C++ Proper use of struct in function arguments

Tags: c++, struct

Quick Question about passing a struct as a function arg. Maybe its a carry over from C that makes no difference in C++.

In many Linked List examples you see them re-declare the word struct in any function argument that takes a struct and I don't understand why. Or any allocation for that matter. A structure is its own object and declaring just the name of the struct is sufficient.

Example:

```
struct Node{

    int data;
    Node * next;
};

// Function to output data.
void printNode(struct Node* myNode){ 

    // Print data of node

}
```

why is the word struct re-declared in the function arg. Declaring type Node* works just fine.

Thanks.

Comment: Yeah you don't need to say `struct` in C++

Comment: This is a C thing. In C one often uses a `typedef` to avoid that, but in C++ you can always use the type without the `struct` or `class` keyword.

Comment: Ahh , That would explain why we use typedef struct in Objective C

Comment: Don't forget the semicolon after the `struct` definition though, I don't think your code will compile as is.

Comment: The word is not redeclared, it's there because you name a struct by its tag. [And some would say that's preferable](http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/typedefs.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a difference between C and C++ use of declarations produced with `struct` keyword:

- In C, `struct` defines a new `struct` *tag*, but not a new *type*
- In C++, `struct` defines a new *type*.

The consequence is that C++ lets you use the name defined in `struct`, while C requires you to either prefix a `struct` to the tag, or use `typedef` to define a new type.

Answer (score 0):

C requires it. C++ does not require it, but allows it for backward compatibility. Do not do this for new code.

Comment: You most certainly *should* do this in new code, if that code is a C binding.

Comment: The question is tagged C++ so what C does bears no relevance for writing new C++

Comment: And new C binding are no longer written for C++ libraries? That's news to me.

Comment: StroryTeller - That's good info moving forward. I'll just get in the habit of using typedef struct.

Comment: @Miek - Don't. It's not required for C++. And as discussed in the thread I linked to your question, it can actually make the C bindings better.

Comment: If you're writing header files for use in C, then you're not writing C++ are you?

Comment: `extern "C"` and the `__cplusplus` macro seem pretty C++ to me

Comment: @Rob K Although you are correct, but for my situation, I write in C, C++ and Objective C and understanding now this issue effects all three is important for me to know. I appreciate the input.

Comment: You didn't say anything in the question about interfacing with code in other languages, so I inferred you wanted to know about pure C++. If you're writing compatibility code, code that's going to be both C and C++, then of course you don't have any choice. But for pure C++, code that's only going to be C++, you shouldn't use it.